# backgrounds tasks by swingworkers become sequential

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, swingworker

I am using SwingWorkers to make my GUI responsive. But I can not understand the following:
I have a remote method I want to call from the GUI as the user presses a button. 
I have inside the action of the button (short for presentation of problem):

```
//in action of button
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<boolean,Void>(){
   @Override
   public boolean doInBackground(){
      return call_remote_method_here();
   }

};
worker.execute();
//some other code
```

My problem is that although the gui seems responsive the actual calls to the remote method are sequential and not concurrent . I noticed it in network traces, and thought that the method was blocking. But then I saw in the traces that the SwingWorkers seem to be running sequential. From

log
2010-09-06 16:58:22,962 [**SwingWorker-pool-4-thread-1**] DEBUG -->First remote method call

I get the response and then the second swingworker runs

2010-09-06 16:58:23,227 [**SwingWorker-pool-4-thread-1**] DEBUG  --> Second remote method call

Why is this happening? I thought that it was random interleaving but I noticed that the 2 instances have the same name? Are the swing workers pooled? Is this a random behavior? Shouln't I see 2 concurrent calls? If they are being reused, is there anything I can do to have concurrent calls and not parallism?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that all Swingworkers run on the same Background-Thread. When you want them to run concurrent you could add them to an Executor Service like this for example:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executor.execute(yourSwingWorker);
```

Source: [Oracle Forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5434659)

Comment: Yes this solves it.Is there any overhead to this, or it is better to abandon SwingWorker and create my own threads

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing wrong with using a threadpool. Its even recommended, since you gain some extra control about when to start threads, how many threads should run at the same time, etc... And concerning SwingWorkers, it just depends on what kind of thread you need. The intent behind SwingWorkers was to keep UI elements updated while having a complex task running in the background and getting information out of this task, while processing or finishing it.

Answer (score 4):

you can perhaps have a look at this [post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5424356).

One of the given solution is to execute the SwingWorker instances using your own executor Service. It seems that a change in jdk 1.6 update 18 changed the default behaviour.